# Kentico - Web Analytics Dashboard constantly refreshes

Tags: kentico

Not much more detail I can add really to that, it has 3 reports on it that track visits from various different periods but the lowest is 12 weeks and yet it just continually refreshes that section.

I'm assuming it's some kind of real time reporting/sample size interval but for the life of me I can't find one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Kentico are you using? Have you checked the hotfixes yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really sounds like a bug fixed in 11.0.9 hotfix:

Dashboards - Repetitive reloading of certain dashboard pages
If the 'Allow preview mode on the live site' setting was disabled, certain widget dashboards in the administration interface reloaded constantly (for example the 'Dashboard' page in the 'Web analytics' application).

or if you can not hotfix workaround should be changing Settings > Content > Content management and change "Allow preview mode on the live site" to true, the issue should go away.